# web.config issues? Gzip no working properly

Tags: iis-7.5, web.config-transform

I read about everything that i could find at the web for gzip compression of iis

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I am aware that the first time gzip won't work in order to create the compressed files... this is the awkward part... i use gtmetrix to see what i can do in order to load faster my webpage... Although the code is correct sometimes for no reason gzip isn't working, according to gmetrix report.. i also use fiddler that also points out the same more or less... does anyone have any idea what might going wrong? Thank You! the server is running iis7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dynamiccontent` in iis roles was missing, once I added that it solved the problem.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer once the system will allows it.